# Exchanging LimSup and Sup

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $m$ be a probability measure on $W \subseteq \mathbb{R}^p$.

Consider a bounded upper semicontinuous function $f: X \times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, where $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is closed and $Y \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ is compact.

- Is the following function $F$ is upper semi-continuous?
  $$ F(x) := \sup_{y \in Y} \int_W f(x,y) m(dw) $$
- Is $F$ upper semi-continuous if $Y$ is just closed?

Comments. By reversed [Fatou's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma) and uniform boundedness of $f$, I was able to show that, for all fixed $x \in X$, $y \mapsto \bar{f}(x,y):= \int_W f(x,y)m(dw)$ is upper semi-continuous. Now I am not sure if
$$ \limsup_{i \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{y \in Y} \bar{f}(x_i,y) \leq \sup_{y \in Y} \limsup_{i \rightarrow \infty} \bar{f}(x_i,y).$$
If this is true, than the above claim on $F$ follows.